# jquery ui dialog box as confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I am, trying to replicate the 'confirm' box of javascript using jquery dialog. This is my code,

```
function customConfirm(customMessage) {
        $("#popUp").html(customMessage);
        $("#popUp").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 240,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "OK": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    alert(true);
                    return true;
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    alert(false);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

But when I tried to alert this method, it shows 'undefined'. It is not waiting for the popup to display. How can i make this customConfirm function to wait for the users input(ok/cancel)?. 
My need is that, customConfirm() method will return either true of false according to user input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need to do is use jQuery.deferred/promise.

http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/

In this example, asyncEvent

1)creates a jquery deferred object

2)has logic for resolve/reject, your ok/cancel

3)returns a deferred.promise() object, which can then be used with a $.when to determine if a deferred object is resolved or rejected (ok/cancel).

What you would do is

1)create a jquery deferred object

2)launch your dialog, with ok/cancel setting the deferred.resolve/reject

3)return a deferred.promise() object,

4)Use the deferred promise object with $.when
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

```
function customConfirm(customMessage) {
    var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred();
    $("#popUp").html(customMessage);
    $("#popUp").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 240,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "OK": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                alert(true);
                dfd.resolve();
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                alert(false);
                dfd.reject();
            }
        }
    });
   return dfd.promise();
}

$.when( customConfirm('hey') ).then(
  function() {
  alert( "things are going well" );
},
function( ) {
  alert( "you fail this time" );
});
```

You could also just use resolve and determine if the confirm was true or false in the $.when,

```
function customConfirm(customMessage) {
    var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred();
    $("#popUp").html(customMessage);
    $("#popUp").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 240,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "OK": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                alert(true);
                dfd.resolve(true);
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                alert(false);
                dfd.resolve(false);
            }
        }
    });
   return dfd.promise();
}

$.when( customConfirm('hey') ).then(
  function(confirm) {

   if(confirm){alert( "things are going well" );}
   else{alert( "you fail this time" );}
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Following this and other examples with jQuery 3.1.0 & jQuery UI 1.12.0 trying to create a confirm dialog. Was creating a default variable before running `$.when()`. Found that the variable got passed before `$.when()` completed. Any suggestions or advice?

Comment: FYI - I found my issue. I was using the anonymous function and variables inside would be lost after execution. Moving to a function that is already defined helped.

Answer (score 7):

This is what I do using zepto with modules deferred and callbacks, works like a charm.
Should be similar for jquery or you can just import the deferred and callbacks modules into your html

```
function customConfirm(customMessage) {
  var d = new $.Deferred();
  $("#popUp").html(customMessage);
  $("#popUp").dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height: 300,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
          "Yes": function () {
              $(this).dialog("close");
              d.resolve()
          },
          "No": function () {
              $(this).dialog("close");
              d.reject();
          }
      }
  });
 return d.promise();
}

customConfirm("Do you Want to delete the File?")
.then(function(){
  console.log("You Clicked Yes")
})
.fail(function(){
  console.log("You Clicked No")
});
```

Comment: This works great. However you are missing a semicolon after `var d = new $.Deferred()`. It should be `var d = new $.Deferred();`

Comment: Thanks fixed. But javascript doesn't care about semi colons.

Comment: To me in the past. How are you? Whatsup? Invest in bitcoin and become rich and save the world.

Answer (score 2):

You should load dialog on document ready function. Call dialog open on `customConfirm` function,

```
  function customConfirm(customMessage) {
    $("#popUp").html(customMessage);
    $("#popUp").dialog("open");
  }

  $(document).ready(function (){
    $("#popUp").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 240,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "OK": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                alert(true);
                return true;
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                alert(false);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

  });
```

Comment: it is not working. still it show the message undefined when i call customConfirm

Comment: Is `customMessage` param has any value? Try to consol.log it.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi, alert(customConfirm) is not valid to show dialog. Try ` $("#confirm").button().click(function() {
                            $("#popUp").html("Hello How ");
                            $("#popUp").dialog("open");
                        });`

Comment: It will definetely show the popup dialog as it is internally calling the dialog.open method. My doubt is that, is it possible to replicate the confirm box in javascript.