# Catch Jquery UI dialog box event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am having an ajax call. In that ajax call I am passing a json to the server. This happens when the person clicks on the delete button. So, before deleting I am creating a Jquery UI dialog box. In that I am asking user whether he is sure to delete.

Now, my problem is when the user clicks I am not able to catch the event. I am assigning  a variable ok to have value when yes or no is clicked in jquery dialog box. But the problem is where I am checking if (ok == 1 ) is called first before the user clicks on yes or no. So in any case if user clicks yes or no the ajax call won't happen.

Both the function is in different scripts file.

The function which does the ajax call is -

```
$("#delete")
    .click(
        function() {
            var sendData = {};
            deleteClicked = 1;
            var passedJSON = null;
            if (null != selectedRowData) {  // if the id in table is not null
                if (null != selectedRowId) {
                    console.log("ID exists --> " + newId);
                    if (rowclickable == 1 ) {          //checking whether row should be deleted or not
                        var testDate = $("#FromDate").val();
                        sendData["FromDateStr"] = testDate;
                        console.log(sendData);
                        passedJSON = JSON.stringify(sendData);
                        console.log(passedJSON);
                        ok = showModalBoxForDelete(ok);            // calling the modal box and storing the value
                        console.log(ok);
                        if (ok == 1) {
                            $
                                .ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    cache: false,
                                    url: deleteURL,
                                    data: passedJSON,
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    cache: false,
                                    async: "true",
                                    contentType: "application/json",
                                    success: function(
                                        data) {
                                        if (1 == data.responseCode) {

                                            $(
                                                    "#FromDate,delete")
                                                .attr(
                                                    "disabled",
                                                    "disabled");
                                            $("#FromDate").datepicker("disable");
                                            table.ajax.reload(null, false); // To load the table
                                            showModalBoxForSuccessfulUpdate("The Goal is Deleted");
                                        } else {
                                            alert(data.responseMessage);
                                        }
                                    },
                                    error: function(data) {
                                        console.log("Server Failure");
                                    }
                                });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

The function which calls the modal box is -

```
function showModalBoxForDelete(ok){
    $("#modelView").dialog({
        autoOpen : false,
        modal : true,
         draggable: false,
        buttons : [ {
            text : "Yes",
            icons : {
                primary : "ui-icon-heart"
            },
            click : function() {
                var ok = 1;
                $(this).dialog("close");
                return ok;
            }
        }, {
            text : "No",
            icons : {
                primary : "ui-icon-heart"
            },
            click : function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                console.log("Retaining the page...");               
            }
        } ]
    });
    $("#modelView" ).dialog("open");
    $("#modelView").text("This will delete the goal. Do you still want to continue?");
    return ok;
}
```

Here the line which checks `if (ok == 1)`  is causing a problem as it will get run before user clicks yes or no.

I am not able to understand what to do now. Can anyone please help?

Comment: the async property should be a boolean not a string (in fact you shouldn't use it at all - it's deprecated and gives user a bad responsiveness page)

Comment: ok will remove it thnks

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263091/jquery-ui-dialog-box-as-confirm

Comment: Hi, I tried using the same described in the question and was I able to resolve my problem thanks a lot!